# jpackage exe does not work with PostgreSQL database connection in JavaFX application

Tags: java, postgresql, javafx, wix, jpackage

I have a JavaFX application that connects to a PostgreSQL database using the driver postgresql-42.6.0.jar. I want to generate an exe for my application using jpackage, but the exe does not work properly. It either does not open at all, or it opens but does not show the content of the panes that use the database connection. The jar of my application works fine, but the exe does not.

I tried to generate the exe using the following command:

```
jpackage -t exe --name "MyApp" --app-version 1.0 --input . --dest . --main-jar "jmr_sports.jar" --icon "C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\JMR Sports\icono.ico" --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-jmods-17.0.9" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.base --java-options "-cp lib/postgresql-42.6.0.jar" --win-shortcut --win-menu
```

I also checked the configuration file MyApp.cfg and made sure that the app.classpath parameter included both the jar of my application and the jar of the driver. I expected the exe to work as the jar of my application, showing the content of the panes that use the database connection.

Another detail of my problem is that the application behaves differently depending on whether I add the `--java-options "-cp lib/postgresql-42.6.0.jar"` parameter or not. Without this parameter, the application opens, but the panes that rely on the database connection are blank. With this parameter, the application does not open at all. I don't understand why this happens. I'm sure the problem is related to the database connection, because I've tried removing the code that uses the database connection, and then the panes show the content that doesn't depend on the database.

**Update**

I have activated the win-console option of jpackage to see the error messages:

```
jpackage -t exe --name "MyApp2" --app-version 1.0 --input ./dist --dest ./exe --main-jar "jmr_sports.jar" --icon "C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\JMR Sports\icono.ico" --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-jmods-17.0.9" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.base --java-options "-cp lib/postgresql-42.6.0.jar" --win-shortcut --win-menu --win-console
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\MyApp2>MyApp2.exe
Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.Main
```

Comment: You have missed off some jars, turn on the win-console flag to see the error messages.

Comment: I don't know if this is actually a problem, but having both `--input` and `--dest` set to the current directory (i.e., `.`) seems weird to me. I would have those as entirely separate directories, possibly with neither being the current directory. That said, I suggest following DuncG's advice and generating the application image with `--win-console`. Then launch the application from the terminal and read the error messages. If you still need help, [edit] your question to add those error messages and, if possible, a true [mre].

Comment: @DuncG I have done what you asked me

Comment: @Slaw I have done what you asked me

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace? Also, you might want to try including the main JAR in the input directory.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `jmr_sports.jar` file is being included in the application image?

Comment: @dan1st That is the complete message that I get when I run the exe from the console. The main JAR is jmr_sports.jar, and it is located in the ./dist directory, which is the input directory

Comment: @Slaw Yes, jmr_sports.jar was included, it is in `C:\Program Files\MyApp2\app`

Comment: Does `jimage list --include **/module-info.class "C:\Program Files\MyApp2\runtime\lib\modules"` show all the modules you expect to be in the run-time image?

Comment: Also, why have `--java-options "-cp lib/postgresql-42.6.0.jar"`? Any JAR files you want to be loaded from the class-path should be contained in a directory that you then specify with `--input`. All JAR files in that directory will automatically be put on the class-path.

Comment: If none of this helps lead to a solution, I think a [mre] will be required for us to provide any further help (create the example from scratch; simply have the main class connect to a PostgreSQL database and exit; show all steps used to build and package the project; don't include JavaFX if it's not important to the problem).

Comment: This is the reason I recommend to create an axecutable fat JAR first, and than take this single JAR and use Jpackage with it.

Comment: It looks like you've not packaged your own application. Vie the cfg file and directory content of the release. Also, don't set --input and --dest to same value.